# Catch undefined TypeError from use of 'eval' in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, eval

I'm getting a console error that I can't seem to clear. Does anyone have suggestions for how to catch/clear this?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined
>       at Array.eval (eval at  (http://brandfeed.app:8001/app/scripts/directives/report-chart.js:133:28), :1:20)

I've narrowed down the error to be either from my use of `eval` on my last line of code, or because of the order of operations this function performs. I tried catching the error with an `if (scope.metric !== undefined)`, but that didn't work.

In the context of this issue, `scope.metric` === `impressions.total`.

```
if ((scope.metric !== undefined) &&(scope.metric !== ""))  {
    var maximumY = d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return eval('d.' + scope.metric);
    });
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.id; }));
    y.domain([-(maximumY * .01), d3.max(data, function(d) { return eval('d.' + scope.metric); })]);
}
```

Comment: methinks you should not use _eval_, and `return d[scope.metric]` what you need. Anyway what is _d_ param? can you provide relevant part code from `report-chart.js`?

Comment: You check to _undefiend_ wrong variable. `Cannot read property 'total' of undefined` say that _scope.metric_ resolve to _total_, but seems that _d_ is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `eval`, you can access the property using bracket notation

```
eval('d.' + scope.metric)

// should be written as

d[scope.metric]
```

Comment: d3 is throwing issues with that notation...

`d3.js:14 Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute y1="NaN"`

Comment: The notation isn't the problem, it's the value. (it's `NaN`)

Comment: Isn't that why I should be using `eval`, though?

Comment: No, it's very rare that you need `eval` for anything. Your problem is that you're trying to use a property of the `d` variable which either doesn't exist or has bad data.